# Plot Graphs in separated window

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a long Jupyter notebook code and there is many cells, which are redrawing the actual graph plot. When I am running cells after changing their contents I need to check the plot, but I always need to scroll up and down. I would prefer to watch the plot changes in separated window (I am using two monitors), so I will change the cell content, run the cell, and then just turn my head and see the plot - without any scrolling. Is there a way how to do that? I know it can be done by Spyder, but I want to do it in Jupyter notebook, since I use a lot of notebook advantages, such as Latex notes and headings between cells. Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could tell us how you print your graph (what library ?). Ipython provide magic command. For example, if you use matplotlib to plot some figures, just add `%matplotlib qt` on top of your cell to make the plots appear in a separate window.

See the list of magic command available [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html).

Comment: I am using matplotlib. I tried before, what you are suggesting, but without any success. The magic command %matplotlib qt (the newer version is %matplotlib notebook) changes graph from inline to interactive, but it is still in the same browser tab and not in separated window, so when I scroll to the code I don't see the graph (In Spyder I used to have the code displayed on first monitor and the interactive graph on second). I am strongly interested, if something like that is possible in Jupyter as well. Thanks